# Extracting date, hour and minute from Instant.now() generated date

Tags: java, datetime, hour, zoneddatetime, java.time.instant

I have this code that generates a date and time,

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Africa/Nairobi" );
Instant instant = Instant.now();
ZonedDateTime zdt = instant.atZone(z);
return zdt.toString();
        
//2018-03-19T09:03:22.858+03:00[Africa/Nairobi]
```

Is there a lib like chrono - https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/ChronoField.html field that I can use to get the date, hour and minute?

Chrono fields does not extract the complete date.

Comment: What do you mean by "get the date"?  You want the day, month and year in separate calls?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Since you seem to have been confused about how to get the date from your `ZonedDateTime`, I should like to supplement [Claudiu Guja’a good and correct answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49357185/5772882).

```
    ZoneId z = ZoneId.of("Africa/Nairobi");
    ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.now(z);
    System.out.println("Date         " + zdt.toLocalDate());
    System.out.println("Year         " + zdt.getYear());
    System.out.println("Month        " + zdt.getMonth());
    System.out.println("Day of month " + zdt.getDayOfMonth());
```

This just printed:

```
Date         2018-03-19
Year         2018
Month        MARCH
Day of month 19
```

Please check the documentation for more methods including `getMonthValue` for the number of the month (1 through 12). I include a link at the bottom. Since `ZonedDateTime` class has a `now` method, you don’t need `Instant.now()` first.

If you wanted an old-fashioned `java.util.Date` object — first answer is: don’t. The modern API you are already using is much nicer to work with. Only if you need a `Date` for some legacy API that you cannot change or don’t want to change just now, get an `Instant` and convert it:

```
    Instant instant = Instant.now();
    Date oldfashionedDateObject = Date.from(instant);
    System.out.println("Old-fashioned java.util.Date " + oldfashionedDateObject);
```

This printed:

```
Old-fashioned java.util.Date Mon Mar 19 12:00:05 CET 2018
```

Even though it says `CET` for Central European Time in the string, the `Date` does not contain a time zone (this confuses many). Only its `toString` method (called implicitly when I append the `Date` to a `String`) grabs the JVM’s time zone setting and uses it for generating the `String` while the `Date` stays unaffected.

In the special case where you just want a `Date` representing the date-time now, again, it’s ill-advised unless you have a very specific need, it’s very simple:

```
    Date oldfashionedDateObject = new Date();
```

The result is the same as above.

### Links

- [`ZonedDateTime` documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html)
- [All about java.util.date](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2017/04/23/all-about-java-util-date/)

Comment: Thank you for the credit. Sadly, I did not notice that I had questions on an answer, otherwise I would have answered myself...

Answer (score 2):

`ZonedDateTime` has methods such as `getHour()`, `getMinute()`, `getMonth`, `getYear`, `getdayOfMonth` and more such, which should suffice. You can simply get the year, month and day of month using their respective methods.

If you want all of this data in a formatted string, you can format the `ZonedDateTime` using a `DateTimeFormatter` to get a string to you liking. Or, there is always the `LocalDate` you can get from the `ZonedDateTime` using its `toLocalDate` method.

Comment: I see, but no date anywhere.

Comment: ok, then how about the .getMonth, .getYear and .getdayOfMonth methods? or do you want all of this data in a formattable string?

Comment: I hope you are not asking for `java.util.Date`.

Comment: `Date` is - simple `millisecond`

Comment: @ClaudiuGuja I just want to extract the date now that i can extract hour and minute. It now seems i need to get date outside of Instant.now()

Comment: and in what format do you want to extract the date? you can simply get the year, month and day of month using thier respective methods, or you can format the ZonedDateTime using a DateTimeFormatter to get a string to you liking. Or, there is always the LocalDate you can get from the ZonedDateTime. What exactly do you want?